Почему программа C++ запускается без ошибок не компилируя её с помощью статистической библиотекой, а с компилятор выдаёт ошибку?
Когда Я компилирую C++ код с помощью GCC не используя статистическую библиотеку то она запускается без ошибок, а когда с помощью её использования то компилятор вылетает с ошибкой, почему так?
Вот например, команда компиляция не используя статистическую библиотеку:
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -g *.cpp && ./a.out

Когда Я запускаю программу то она запускается без ошибок и не вылетает.
А теперь вот команды компиляции статистической библиотеки и самого кода:
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -g -c parser.cpp data.cpp tools.cpp && ar rvs libTurboINI.a *.o
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -g -L. -lTurboINI main.cpp

А вот с использованием статистической библиотеки компилятор вылетает с ошибкой.
Вот сама ошибка:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYqFNVP.o: in function `std::__detail::_MakeUniq<TurboINI::parser>::__single_object std::make_unique<TurboINI::parser, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/unique_ptr.h:1065: undefined reference to `TurboINI::parser::parser(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYqFNVP.o: in function `std::default_delete<TurboINI::parser>::operator()(TurboINI::parser*) const':
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/unique_ptr.h:95: undefined reference to `TurboINI::parser::~parser()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Хочу отметить что в коде Я использую smart pointers-ы, такие, как std::unique_ptr и std::shared_ptr.

Попробуйте поместить библиотеку после main.cpp -- g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -g -L. main.cpp -lTurboINI (если не поможет, попробуйте описать свою либу так --  --start-group -lTurboINI --end-group (хотя это применяют к нескольким библиотекам с "взаимными перекрестными ссылками"))

@avp спасибо за ответ! Перемещение библиотеки в команде компиляции после source файла main.cpp сработало, программа запускается без ошибок.

Я не использую надстройки над make (xmake, cmake и т.п. Это как кубик Рубика в любом нетривиальном случае (собственно, как и кресты (т.е. С++) по сравнению с Си))

@avp извиняюсь за введение Вас в недопонимание. Я попробовал скомпилировать с помощью xmake ещё раз и всё заработало. Я Сам в недопонимании.

Ну, работает и ладно. Я думаю, вы поняли, что причина ошибки в алгоритме линкера, он не ищет определения символов в ранее "отлинкованной" либе, но  в каждой вновь просматриваемой ищет все еще не разрешенные символы. Поэтому либы надо перечислять в конце.
